# how to make php exit on E_NOTICE?

Tags: php, error-handling

Normally php script continues to run after E_NOTICE, is there a way to elevate this to fatal error in context of a function, that is I need only to exit on notice only in my functions but not on core php functions, that is globally.

Comment: Why do you need to restrict it to your own functions? If a core function throws an E_NOTICE, that usually means you're using it wrong (in your own function). So I think you should want to catch all E_NOTICEs. Unless you're manually triggering a notice yourself using `trigger_error`, in which case you should trigger an E_USER_NOTICE instead, which is easy to distinguish.

Comment: I primarily thought about making it exit on E_NOTICE on my functions, at least some of them. I think is meaningless to write exceptions for E_USER_NOTICE since in this case any programmers aim is to really put that notice into work and continue executing.

Comment: "Notices only in my functions" Do you mean that you want to [trigger](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) them yourself? or they are normal "core" `E_NOTICE`s which occur in your functions?

Comment: Normal core notices. My own should be intact, since I intented them to be notices in the first place. I just don't agree with php authors choosing which error stops script and which not.

Comment: If you're generating your own errors, I would advise you not to. Best practice is not to use exceptions instead. PHP's exception handling is much better than it's handling of the E_XXX error types.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could create a custom error handler to catch `E_NOTICE`s.

This is untested but should go into the right direction:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
 {
  if ($errno == E_USER_NOTICE)
   die ("Fatal notice");
  else
   return false; // Leave everything else to PHP's error handling

 }
```

then, set it as the new custom error handler using [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) when entering your function, and restore PHP's error handler when leaving it:

```
function some_function()
{

// Set your error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

... do your stuff ....

// Restore old error handler
set_error_handler($old_error_handler);

}
```

Comment: "that is I need only to exit on notice only in my functions but not on core php functions, that is globally"

Comment: @Rikudo That's exactly what the above is doing, isn't it? What is missing?

Comment: He doesn't want it to die on a php core E_NOTICE but only a E_USER_NOTICE triggered by his functions :)

Comment: @Rikudo Actually, where does the OP ever mention `E_USER_NOTICE`?

Comment: Good question. Asked OP to clarify.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I didn't know about that is is possible to output error handler from set_error_handler and then reapply it after function is done. Neat thing.

Answer (score 4):

You use a custom error handler using [`set_error_handler()`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

```
<?php

    function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        if ($errno == E_USER_NOTICE) {
            die("Died on user notice!! Error: {$errstr} on {$errfile}:{$errline}");
        }
        return false; //Will trigger PHP's default handler if reaches this point.
    }

    set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');

    trigger_error('This is a E_USER_NOTICE level error.');
    echo "This will never be executed.";


?>
```

## [Working Example](http://codepad.org/jLBEqpt8)