# Exit execution on calling disabled function

Tags: php

I have disabled a few functions using `disable_functions` in **php.ini**. On calling these functions I can see in my logs that a warning is generated like:

> PHP Warning:  somefunction() has been disabled for security reasons in file

However the rest of the file is executed normally.

Is there any way to block the execution (or exit code) once a `disabled_function` is called. Something like a callback function maybe?

Or else is it possible to turn that Warning into an Error?

PHP version `PHP 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.3`

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2749591/3933332

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050067/how-to-make-php-exit-on-e-notice

Comment: @Steve thanks for the link. Looks pretty much close to what I want.

Comment: `disable_functions` will effectively *disable* the functions listed. Meaning they will not be available anymore in PHP. If your script *works* as expected, then these functions are called in conditional blocks which does not get executed during your test, otherwise it would throw a fatal error and exit immediately.

Comment: @hek2mgl thats what I desired. However cause of some reason its not throwing error, instead its given a detailed warning as posted in my question.